# How to get Youtube's Trending Music Feed using its API

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-channels

Basically, what I want to get is Youtube's Trending Music in UK. I want to get the videos that are recently uploaded and is trending starting with few views.

Example:
http://www.youtube.com/channel/HCp-Rdqh3z4Uc/videos?query=NErAuLQauvw&view=22&feature=g-logo

I am confused which one of the feeds below is more applicable to me.

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/channelstandardfeeds/most_viewed?time=today&v=2
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/UK/on_the_web_Music

Please help me with this. Your answer and ideas will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Youtube channels usually start with the prefix UC. In this case the channel starts with HC what for as for I know means hidden channel. This means that you can only access them via the api if you have the right credentials.

This channels are maintained by youtube and they do not share that info for third party apps.

So if you want to rip it you will have to make a own webservice that searches the youtube site and stores the video id's or build an html parser or something like that in your application.